# MarbleAbstractPresenter to override Marble InputHandler in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, marble

The MarbleAbstractPresenter class is present in the api(https://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/classMarble_1_1MarbleAbstractPresenter.html) as well as the current source code(https://github.com/KDE/marble/blob/master/src/lib/marble/MarbleAbstractPresenter.h), but cannot be added to the Qt project.

```
#include <marble/MarbleWidgetInputHandler.h> //Works
#include <marble/MarbleAbstractPresenter.h> //No Valid Expression
```

The MarbleAbstractPresenter file is not in the /export/include/marble/ directory like most of the other .h files. Is there a way to add this file so that it can be read by Qt or is there a different way to create an MarbleAbstractPresenter so that a command like this can run?

```
MarbleWidgetInputHandler *a = new MyInputHandler(new MarbleAbstractPresenter(new MarbleMap()), mapWidget);
```